# input$plot_hover not retaining enough decimal points

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to have R shiny print out the sample information when hovering over a data point in a ggplot2 geom_point plot. The axes for my plot have 4 decimal points but if I print plot_hover$x and $y it only returns two decimal points, so the output ends up being the same for every point on the plot.  I noticed the examples on the shiny site also only output two decimal points.  Is there a way to change this to retain more information in input$plot_hover?

Comment: maybe this comes from the `print`. Please provide a small example to reproduce your issue

Comment: In the course of putting together the small example, I discovered the root of the problem was with how the plot was overlaid on a map and I wasn't carfeul with layers.

Comment: Good! Creating a MWE is often the quickest way to solve an issue

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproduceable example this is tough, so all of these are complete guesses as to what your actual problem is.  Here are some stabs in the dark as to how to fix a problem where ggplot is not printing enough digits.

@HubertL: You may be able to control the number of printed digits using

```
options(digits = 10)
```

Or use a wrapper around any calculations to specify the number of rounded digits to include in a calculation or output from a function

```
round(calculation, 10)
```

Additionally, this could be an issue with the space on the plot axis.  You may want to try decreasing the size of the text on the axis within the plot using

```
plot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8))
```

And you could add `angle` in there as well to rotate the numbers to validate there is enough space.